Running Cron job on Drupal 10 site with CiviCRM 5.79.1
When I run this command through SSH, it is executed properly
drush \
    -l https://www.instituutvlaamsevolkskunst.be \
    --uid=3 \
    civicrm:api job.execute \
    --quiet

When I add it to crontab, nothing happens
* 5 * * * drush -l https://www.instituutvlaamsevolkskunst.be --uid=3 civicrm:api job.execute --quiet

What am I doing wrong ?
I am following these instructions: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/#crontab
Stefaan

What unix user does cron run under? Does it have drush in it's PATH? Can also remove the --quiet and add >> /tmp/drushout.txt 2>> /tmp/drusherr.txt to get some logging.

As Demerit's comment suggests, running a command manually vs. as a cron has some subtle differences (PATH being one), because .. paranoia.  I always include the full path to my drush for that reason (especially because drush "launching" is always tricky because it tries to do a lot of magic stuff like figure out a doc root and base site). For debugging, you can also add a MAILTO line at the top of the crontab so that the errors get sent to you.

tnx, first of all I modified the command from * 5 * * to * /5 * * ;) Can someone point me to clear instructions or provide some sample files ?
